# Vega-Lite / Altair: How to Center or Crop a Map of Europe?

Tags: data-visualization, gis, vega, vega-lite, altair

I have some data on European countries. I'm trying to create a visualization in Altair / Vega-Lite using the world-110m data. Everything technically works fine, except that coded boundaries of the countries also include far-away territories, producing a terrible map that looks like this:

[image: Bad Europe Map]

Here is my code:

```
countries = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url, 'countries')
source = df.copy()

map = alt.Chart(countries).mark_geoshape(
    stroke='black'
    ).encode(
    color=alt.Color('SomeStat:Q', sort="descending", scale=alt.Scale(
        scheme='inferno', domain=(min_value,max_value)), legend=alt.Legend(title="", tickCount=6))
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(source, 'CountryId', ['SomeStat', 'CountryName'])
).project(
    type='mercator'
)
```

Is there a way to crop this map or center it so that I'm only getting Europe and not far-flung territories all over the world?

Alternatively, is there a better public dataset I should be using that only includes Europe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have your `df` dataset, so I post rather simple example.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

countries = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url, 'countries')

alt.Chart(countries).mark_geoshape(
    fill='#666666',
    stroke='white'
).project(
    type= 'mercator',
    scale= 350,                          # Magnify
    center= [20,50],                     # [lon, lat]
    clipExtent= [[0, 0], [400, 300]],    # [[left, top], [right, bottom]]
).properties(
    title='Europe (Mercator)',
    width=400, height=300
)
```

[image]

You can control the map view by `scale` and `center`, along with its actual plot size (`width` and `height`).

- `scale`: magnifying parameter
- `center`: center point of the view

If you need to further crop any part of the map, `clipExtent` can be useful. Please be careful - this array represents the pixel size, not geographical coordinates. (In the above example I have set it `[[0, 0], [400, 300]]` so it keeps the entire `400x300 px` view.

Comment: That works great! I was looking all over the documentation, but just couldn't figure out where it would be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cropping you can filter the countries ... for a single country use

```
.transform_filter((alt.datum.id)==32)
```

where the number is the iso code (so this will show Argentina).

For a list of countries, make a list of iso codes and then use this answer https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/676 to filter on a list... eg

```
list_to_show = [660,28,32]
background = alt.Chart(source).mark_geoshape(fill="white").transform_filter(alt.FieldOneOfPredicate(field='id', oneOf=list_to_show))
```